# Armazenar mensagem SMS em variável

Tags: c++, arduino, sms

Estou com problemas para salvar uma mensagem SMS em uma variável. A ideia é mandar um SMS com um comando e mais tarde usar um operador condicional para ativar ou desativar um relé.

Mas não consigo salvar a mensagem SMS. Sempre que eu tento salvá-la, ela assume o valor de:

`" ÿ "`.

Estou usando um módulo GSM sim900 com o Arduino.

Segue o código que estou tentando usar:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial cell(2,3); 
void setup()
{
    cell.begin(19200);
    cell.println("AT+CMGF=1"); 
    delay(200);
    cell.println("AT+CNMI=3,2,0,0");
    delay(200);
}
void loop() 
{
    if(cell.available() >0)    // se o shild resceber uma msg
    {          
        delay(10);
        msg=cell.read();     // salve ela na variavel  msg
        Serial.println(msg);// mostra o valor do "msg" NESSE ponto ela esta valendo ÿ 
        if (msg=='a')     // se o primeiro caracter for "a"
        {
            delay(10);
            msg=cell.read();
            if (msg=='0')   // se o segundo caracter for "0"
            {
                delay(10);
                msg=cell.read();
                if (msg=='e')   // se o terceiro caracter for "e"
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Quando imprimo a mensagem no serial, seu valor é `ÿ`, por que  isso?

Andei pesquisado e descobri que antes de dizer ao Arduino para armazenar a SMS, temos que dizer pra ele "escutar" a serial que recebe a mensagem e isto está relacionado ao:

```
gsm.listen();
```

Mas não entendi a relação muito bem.

Comment: @brasofilo a linguagem do Arduino se chama Arduino ;)

Comment: A linguagem do Arduino é C!

Comment: eu estou estudando umas quatro ou 5 linguagem de programação, foi mal não ter colocado... to moh perdido, obrigado

Comment: @Trxplz0 Acho que o código do OP está em C, mas a linguagem oficial do Arduino [se chama Arduino mesmo](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Introduction).

Comment: vc esta imprimindo `msg` antes de ler `msg`.

Comment: áh eé... o erro de vc esta imprimindo msg antes de ler, foi de agora na hora de postar... ops

Comment: descobri mais algumas coisas, ates de entrar no loop devemos dizer aonde o modulo deve salvar a sms com o codigo `AT+CPMS=?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esse code resolve meu problema, consigo editar as sms. usando vetores :)

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM(2, 3);
int x =0;
float temp=0;
char data [256];

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("ler mensagem");
  delay(1000); 
  //mySerial.flush();
  for (x=0;x < 255;x++)
  {
    data[x]='\0';
  }
  x=0;
  do{
while(SIM.available()==0);
data[x]=SIM.read();
x++;
if(data[x-1]==0x0D&&data[x-2]=='"') 
{ 
 x=0;
}
}
while(!(data[x-1]=='K'&&data[x-2]=='O')); 
  data[x-3]='\0'; 
  Serial.println(data[1]);
 temp=0;
 temp=data[7];
Serial.println(temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Penso que `'ÿ'` tenha o valor `-1`.

De acordo com a documentação de [`SoftwareSerial: read`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialRead)

> **Returns**
>   the character read, or -1 if none is available

se a função devolver `-1` quer dizer que não há caracteres disponiveis.

```
    msg = cell.read();
    if (msg == -1) /* nao ha caracteres disponiveis */;
```